# Finding the root of a javascript function on a website

Tags: javascript

I would like to find the parent JavaScript file for a function, For Example If i was to inspect an element on this page and it has an 

 `"onclick="poster(3459345_5453)"` 
 
how could i find out what JavaScript file the function "poster()" is in. So if there is 3 JavaScript files linked to this website, and i don't know which one of them has the function "poster()" how could i find it?

I have already tried right using Ctrl+f in the inspect element area of chrome and was unable to locate the function.

Comment: May I ask what are you trying to achieve? Maybe there's a better way

Comment: Go to console, type in `debugger;poster(3459345_5453);` - step into. A modern console will show you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest to use Firefox Firebug. Open Console and just type "poster". It will output function signature. You can hover on it to find out file or click on it to navigate to Script of Firebug. Check out screenshots.

- https://blog.gaurangjadia.com/?attachment_id=835
- https://blog.gaurangjadia.com/?attachment_id=836

Also, you can put breakpoints and debug your scripts. It is nice and powerful web development tool.

Example is at http://code.gaurangjadia.com/stackoverflow/18551051/